# CAF Promise Result

Tags: promise, c++14, actor, c++-actor-framework

In CAF, response promises allow an actor to send and receive other messages prior to replying to a particular request. My issue is how to use the result of that promise.

```
// function-based, statically typed, event-based API
  adder::behavior_type calculator_master(adder::pointer self) {
  auto w = self->spawn(worker);
   return {
[=](add_atom x, int y, int z) -> result<int> {
  auto rp = self->make_response_promise<int>();
  self->request(w, infinite, x, y, z).then([=](int result) mutable {
    rp.deliver(result);
  });
  return rp;
}
```

};
}

I basically have to use the value of rp before the return statement. Please let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you expand on the "value of rp before the return statement" part? `request(...).then(...)` will always return immediately and event-based actors are supposed to not block. What do you want to do that you can't do in the `.then(...)` continuation?

Comment: So what I want to do is call two actors B1 and B2 (which work using promises) in actor A. And then use both the results of B1 & B2 to do the computation in A. So after the self->request, I have to use the return result outside the self->request.

Answer (score 0):

I just share some of my understanding.

Response promise is not exactly the same as future/promise (e.g. std::future and std::promise), so you cannot use response promise as you use future/promise.

One usage of response promise is to reply something to the sender while the task is not yet done. Supposed actor `A` sends a request to actor `B` but `B` is not the one that handles the request. `B` delivers the request to another actor `C` and `C` handles the request. In this case, `B` forwards the request to `C` and has to reply something to `A`. `B` cannot be blocked and wait for `C`, otherwise `B` cannot handle new requests. At the end, `B` sends a response promise to `A`. The response promise created by `B` is actually used by `A` so that `A` can wait for the result of `C`.

P.S. Sad that I don't have enough reputation to make a comment.